# httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression does not set "Accept_Encoding: gzip" header

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, httpwebrequest

I am using a web service reference in my .net 3.0 app and I'm trying to set up gzip decoding.

When I use SoapUI the responses are compressed with gzip because the the header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' is set in the request.  When my .net request is sent it does not have this header so the server is not compressing the response.

I found this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CompressibleHTTP20.aspx) which describes exactly what I want to do.  I implemented the code and verified with the debugger that it was being executed on every request, but it is still not adding the 'Accept-Encoding:gzip' header.

Next I added the header manually in the class from the link.

```
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
```

Finally I received a compressed response from the server! But no, now I get an malformed xml exception which I'm pretty sure is because the response is not being decompressed even though the following is set by using the class from the link.

```
httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;;
```

I cannot understand what is going wrong.

Comment: `.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;` adds the `"Accept-Encoding"` header, setting that yourself might interfer with AutomaticDecompression. You should use `(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create()` as well, istead of that ugly reflection used in the page you link to.

Comment: Since i am using a web reference i am just calling methods in the referenced api and am not explicitly creating the webrequests.  Those creations are handled by .net somehow and that is why i used this reflection code.  If i do not add the header for "Accept-Encoding", the request does not have that header even when i set .AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip; Am i seeing this issue because i am using a web reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured out a solution to my problem.

Since I am using a web reference you have to set `EnableDecompression = true` on the web reference object.

So the solution is something like this

```
var client = new ReferredService
{
    EnableDecompression = true
}
```

where ReferredService is the web reference name.